# Pyglossary seemed to install but won't run - error message - what next?

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Linux and also to Python. I am trying to run [Pyglossary](https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary) on Python 3.10.6 (preinstalled) on ubuntu 22.04.1.

I installed it using pip (pip install --upgrade pyglossary). There was a warning that it had defaulted to a user installation and that /home/linux/.local/bin wasn't on the path. I added it to the path.

When I try to run it I get the following error message:

```
[CRITICAL] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linux/.local/bin/pyglossary", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyglossary/ui/main.py", line 790, in main
    sys.exit(0 if ui_module.UI().run(**runKeywordArgs) else 1)
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyglossary/ui/ui_gtk.py", line 962, in __init__
    screenW, screenH = getWorkAreaSize()
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyglossary/ui/ui_gtk.py", line 88, in getWorkAreaSize
    rect = monitor.get_workarea()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_workarea'
```

I had previously tried to install it using both pip and sudo apt commands but later ran apt remove and pip uninstall so hopefully that's not connected.

I have no idea what to do next - any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows:
Open with an editor this file:
/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyglossary/ui/ui_gtk.py

go to line 88 and change this function a little.

```
def getWorkAreaSize():
    display = gdk.Display.get_default()
    try:
      monitor = display.get_primary_monitor()
      rect = monitor.get_workarea()
      return rect.width, rect.height
    except:
      monitor = display.get_monitor_at_point(1,1)     
      rect = monitor.get_workarea()
      return rect.width, rect.height
```

The values rect.width and rect.height are not set by the original function display.get_workarea().

Most likely this is caused because you (at least I) use a build-in screen. Are you also using a laptop? They have a build-in screen setting. I think the setting for a primary monitor does not exists, unless you attach your laptop to an external monitor (my 4 cents)